# How to solve Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

When I connect my real device to `android studio`, I will get this in my `logCat`. I can't see what's really caused my app crashed since this are the only message I get. I have tried many method but no success. It really drive me crazy !

```
11-11 21:31:59.011  12352-12358/com.example.project.project
D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
```

1. Tools --> Android --> Enable ADB Integration.
2. In Eclipse: Window->Show View->(Other->Debug->)Breakpoints.
3. Disable and enable the USB Debugging option in Developer options

These three methods doesn't work for me. Any idea?

Below shows the screen shot of my `Android Studio`

[image]

Comment: plz give me a  screenshot of your android studio.

Comment: @tinysunlight edited. Please have a look

Comment: Try turn "only debuging app" to "no filter" at right-top of logcat

Comment: @tinysunlight I tried. But if the app crashed, it doesn't show logcat error. It throws many logCat but not the error

Comment: Try to use try- catch and log error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94821/discussion-between-hoo-and-tiny-sunlight).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked this? make sure you only have one `com.example.project.project`. Not sure whether this work for you or not, but at least it works for me.

Good luck.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man! Just realize I have a lot of `com.example.project.project`. After removed all, it works like charm now